# QuestPDF: Can you display Datatables using the Table element and generate a pdf with it without using the previewer?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm fairly still a beginner in development, so bear with me please (and sorry for any confusion on my part, it's been a long day). I'm having some issues right now with trying out QuestPDF to see if it's going to work for me, for a particular project I am working on. Basically, I'm trying to figure out if I can get it to use the information from a Datatable that's currently sitting in SQL and display it in their Table element.

Another problem I am having is, I can't generate the PDF with the current table I've made. I currently don't have the previewer installed, since I thought I could just go ahead and generate the PDF by calling my method that I'm putting this in.

```
public static void CreatePDF(DataTable dt)
        {

         
              void ComposeTable(IContainer container)
            {
                container.Table(table =>
                {
                   
                    table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.ConstantColumn(25);
                        columns.RelativeColumn(3);
                        columns.RelativeColumn();
                        columns.RelativeColumn();

                    });


                    table.Header(header =>
                    {
                        header.Cell().Text("First Name");
                        header.Cell().Text("Last Name");
                        header.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Middle");
                        header.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Date of birth");



                    });

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        table.Cell().Text(dt);


                    }
                });
                var document = CreatePDF(dt);

                document.GeneratePdf("F:\repos\\Mikayla\\Test\\test.pdf");


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.
You just need to add cells to the table sequentially. The library itself will arrange them in columns.

In your example:

```cs
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    table.Cell().Text(row[0].ToString());
    table.Cell().Text(row[1].ToString());
    table.Cell().Text(row[2].ToString());
    table.Cell().Text(row[3].ToString());
}
```

Of full example:

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
        dt.Columns.Add("MiddleName");
        dt.Columns.Add("DateOfBirth");
        for (var i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            var nr = dt.NewRow();
            nr[0] = $"{i + 1} First Name";
            nr[1] = $"{i + 1} Last Name";
            nr[2] = $"{i + 1} Middle Name";
            nr[3] = $"{i + 1} Birth Date";
            dt.Rows.Add(nr);
        }

        var pdfdoc = CreatePDF(dt);
        var fileName = "c:\\temp\\so_test.pdf";
        pdfdoc.GeneratePdf(fileName);
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", fileName);
    }

    public static Document CreatePDF(DataTable dt)
    {
        void ComposeTable(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Table(table =>
            {

                table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
                {
                    columns.ConstantColumn(100);
                    columns.RelativeColumn(3);
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                    columns.RelativeColumn();

                });


                table.Header(header =>
                {
                    header.Cell().Text("First Name");
                    header.Cell().Text("Last Name");
                    header.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Middle");
                    header.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Date of birth");

                });

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    table.Cell().Text(row[0].ToString());
                    table.Cell().Text(row[1].ToString());
                    table.Cell().Text(row[2].ToString());
                    table.Cell().Text(row[3].ToString());
                }
            });
        }

        return Document.Create(container =>
        {
            container.Page(page =>
            {
                page.Content().Column(c => ComposeTable(c.Item()));
            });
        });
    }
}
```